# Swift: Optional variable in function signature showing error Method cannot be marked @objc because the type

Tags: swift4

I'm working in swift framework but I need to support ObjC. But I have a function like this:

```
@objc public func doingSomething(thing:String?,time:Int?)->String{

    return result
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C

Any of you knows a work around this error?, or how can I fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that integers are a primitive type in Objective-C, so the language is not capable of assigning `nil` to an integer-typed variable. Therefore, you cannot have `Int?` in the signature of a method that is exposed to Objective-C.

As a workaround, you can either make the parameter an `Int` and define a sentinel value to represent a nil value (`NSNotFound` is an example found in the various "indexOf" methods in the frameworks; `0` may work in some cases), or else you can type the parameter as an `NSNumber?` since `NSNumber` is an object type and thus can be `nil`.